# Is Purim recorded in Persian/Medean records?

Tags: history, purim, haman, esther--the-woman, mordechai

In the book [Let My Nation Live](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1578197821), there are sources brought down that one of the reasons Purim was established even in spite of possible tensions with gentiles was that either way it would be recorded in Persian and Medean records, as was commonplace, and Mordechai too was mentioned.

Further, this is one of the reasons why HaShem is never mentioned (as to not have HaShem's name changed in the Persian records.)

So, is Mordechai, Esther, or the story of Purim actually found in any of their records?

Comment: This fact is brought in Megillah 7a. As far as I know, ancient Persian texts alluding to Purim have yet to be found, although other findings prove that the author/s of the Esther were deeply knowledgeable about Persian culture.

Comment: I think so. Persians recorded everything.

Comment: If you can find a copy, you should check out “Comprehensive History of the Jews of Iran” by Habib Levy. He was a top authority on the subject and documented sources from both Persian and Muslim sources that track in detail parallel histories of the Jews from the destruction of the first Temple onward. The book was originally written in Farsi but was later translated into English.

Comment: I believe any records we have of these events from extrabiblical sources are always from a much later date. For example Muslim scholars mention certain events and names, but these scholars are hundreds if not a thousand+ years after the events of Purim.

Comment: Don't forget, the megila itself in 10:2 states that whole story of Mordechai is written in the chronicles of Madai and Paras.

Comment: I am surprised there's no record of these chronicles.

Comment: @Mordechai why be surprised? we have very little in terms of records of the persians. much of what history knows about persia comes from greek historians and not the persians themselves, because that’s what has survived. granted, the greeks did not do such a great job recording persian history as new archeological findings prove, etc